# Авторизация с помощью модуля requests

Tags: python, requests

Пытаюсь авторизироваться на сайте, но не получается и сайт выкидывает меня на страницу обратно логиниться.
Помогите разобраться в чем моя ошибка. Только начал изучать этот модуль.

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'http://passport.vpgame.com/signin?'
    account = 'qnbalnov@emlpro.com'
    password = 'Lflexo23@'
    device_id = 'd3a231cd2bce4a5acee394e57a5e4c10'
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(username=account, password=password)
    c.post(url, data = login_data)
    page = c.get('http://www.vpgame.com/user/my.html')
    print(page.content)
```

Comment: Выкладывать настоящий пароль публично — безусловно отличная идея

Comment: не нужен этот аккаунт (он пустой) . может кто захочет залогинится, чтобы разобраться